# Using Selenium to grab weather data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been struggling all day from [this weather.gov page](https://w2.weather.gov/climate/xmacis.php?wfo=guam) to grab the average temperatures in the last 10 years. What I want my python script to do is select the following:

a) Guam Intl Airport from Location
b) Calendar day summaries from Product
c) 2011-2021 from Year Range
d) Avg temp from Variable
e) Go from View

After View, I will eventually use beautiful soup to print out the table, but I need to complete this step first.

What I have so far is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\myPath\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://w2.weather.gov/climate/xmacis.php?wfo=guam"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="input_block"]/select/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

However, I got the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class="input_block"]/select/option[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Any assistance to solve this problem is truly appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? What are the issues that you are currently facing? Can you provide a more complete code showing your efforts?

Comment: Long story short, I don't know what xpath or css-selector I should use. I've looked everywhere to see if there were past solutions to this and either the formatting is completely different from the path that I would get or I am having trouble understanding how to get the path they are using.

Comment: The part of the site you are trying to access is actually loading in an iframe. You can either just go to the iframe [site](https://nowdata.rcc-acis.org/guam/) and use selenium from there, or use ```driver.switch_to_frame()``` and [navigate](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) while in the iframe

Comment: @BLuta Please [edit the question](/posts/66039159/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66039159/edit).

Comment: @goalie1998 Apologies for the late response, but I wanted to thank you for all your help. Your last bit of advice was able to allow me to get my code working.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `iframe` you need to switch the context so you can work inside it, your `iframe` name is `'routine'` - use `driver.switch_to.frame("name")` or
`driver.switch_to.frame("id of the element")` to handle it

```
url = "https://w2.weather.gov/climate/xmacis.php?wfo=guam"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame('routine')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="input_block"]/select/option[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use the service https://gridforecast.com/api **Current weather** and **Air temperature statistics**